# Clean Data - how to remove slash(/) between two words and the Bracket ()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, data-cleaning

I am pretty new to programming and Python. I have a list of string:

```
['Iraqi', 'Freedom/Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', '(Afghanistan),', 'have', '(other', 'than', 'call', 'publications)']
```

How do I clean all the slash between two words and the bracket enclosed in any word/words. A clean data would be:

```
['Iraqi', 'Freedom', 'Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', 'Afghanistan,', 'have', 'other', 'than', 'call', 'publications']
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help to know what you have tired so far based on your own research; `re.sub`, `str.replace`, etc? Note that we ask for a [mcve] here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

`\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

```
lst=['Iraqi', 'Freedom/Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', '(Afghanistan),', 'have', '(other', 'than', 'call', 'publications)']

new=re.findall('\w+',' '.join(lst))
```

---

Output:

```
['Iraqi', 'Freedom', 'Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', 'Afghanistan,', 'have', 'other', 'than', 'call', 'publications']
```

Without using `re`. You can use `str.strip()` and `str.split()`.

```
[i.strip('()') for s in lst for i in s.split('/')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me name your list:

```
a = ['Iraqi', 'Freedom/Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', '(Afghanistan),', 'have', '(other', 'than', 'call', 'publications)']
```

First, to separate all elements by the slash you can do

```
c = [j for elem in  for j in elem.split("/") ]

And now all in one,
```

c = [j for elem in a for j in re.sub(r'[()]', "", elem).split("/") ]

Second, let's say that you want to remove a set of charachters from each element from the list, for example `['(',')']`

For this you can build a regular expression:

```
d = [re.sub(r'[(\)]', "", elem) for elem in c]
```

And the result is

```
['Iraqi', 'Freedom', 'Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 
'Enduring', 'Freedom', 'Afghanistan,', 'have', 'other', 'than', 'call', 'publications']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this.

```
data_list = ['Iraqi', 'Freedom/Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', '(Afghanistan),', 'have', '(other', 'than', 'call', 'publications)']

out_put_list = []
for data in data_list:
    if '/' in data:
        out_put_list.extend(data.split("/"))
    else:
        out_put_list.append(data.replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))

print(out_put_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension:

```
a = ['Iraqi', 'Freedom/Operation', 'New', 'Dawn', 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring',
 'Freedom', '(Afghanistan),', 'have', '(other', 'than', 'call', 'publications)']


b = [ i.split('/') for i in a]
b = [ i for row in b for i in row]
b = [ i.strip().strip(',').strip('(').strip(')') for i in b]

print(b)
['Iraqi', 'Freedom', 'Operation', 'New', 'Dawn',
 'and', 'Operation', 'Enduring', 'Freedom',
 'Afghanistan', 'have', 'other', 'than',
 'call', 'publications']
```